# Reviving FCM token, but onMessageRecived is not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have add the below code in another app, but not working here

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "<<!!>>";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
      Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        sendNotification("notication");

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);
    }

    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().beginWith(work).enqueue();
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }


    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you registered your service in Manifest.xml?

Comment: Please, clarify what _not working_ means.

Comment: Have you added the google-services.json file to this project code if you have applied the same code to this project? @Ashim

Comment: yes i have followed all the steps 4-6 times. but still no response

Comment: @noiaverbale i am unable to find but why i am facing this issue. i have tried same thing with another project. another project its working.